# Using multiple SSL certificates in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, profiles

Can't figure this out on my own. 
I'm developing web applications where i have to test multiple client certificates that have different roles in Chrome.

In Firefox this i easy because i can make different profiles with separate certificates installed.

Is there any way to achieve this in chrome or do i have to remove and install a different certificate each time?

I've already tried Chromes user profiles but certificates aren't bound to the profiles. I've also tried to find a option to force certification dialog to show up every time i open a specific site but it doesn't appear to bee any other solution than to reset the browser cache. Usually i could just override the authentication check in the code but now the authentication is done in the server software so i have to use the right certificate.

I'm running Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 so there might be some other tricks to use too.

Comment: have you tried to use a different user data dir with the `--user-data-dir` option?

Comment: Thanks, this helps in a way that i can now run multiple instances of Chrome simultaneously and have different certificates applied in each browser. The different instances however still share the same certificate storage so i have to select the right certificate each time from the promt dialog.